# How change action icons dynamically in android wear

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, wear-os

I have created a android wear app which support my handheld application.
The android wear app showing notifications and related actions top perform.

I have created android wear notifications and added two actions for pause,resume and stop

I need to replace the pause action by  resume action dynamically, that means if user press pause action need to change to resume action.

My code is

```
Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PauseActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                 0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         Intent stopIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopActivity.class);
         PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                 0, stopIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


         Notification notification =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                            .setContentTitle("Swipe up to view")
                            .setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent)
                            .extend(new WearableExtender()
                                    .setDisplayIntent(displayPendingIntent))
                            .addAction(R.drawable.pause_btn, "Pause", pausePendingIntent)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.stop_btn, "Stop", stopPendingIntent)
                                    .build();
```

My requirement is When user clicks on the pause button i need to change that by Resume Icon.

Advance thanks for all...
My screen looks like

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You need to just post new notification when user clicks that action in order to refresh it.
The old notification will be updated so while posting a new one change the "pause" icon to "resume" icon + do the same with labels.

---

### Also: I would recommend you to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` here

Define your intents like that:

```
Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.ACTION_PAUSE, null, context, MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent resumeIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.ACTION_RESUME, null, context, MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.class);
PendingIntent resumePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resumeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.ACTION_STOP, null, context, MediaPlayerActionsReceiver.class);
PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

They all will be delivered to the same component (`MediaPlayerActionsReceiver`), but with different action declared.

Then create your MediaPlayerActionsReceiver class:

```
public class MediaPlayerActionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public final static String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.package.receiver.action_pause";
    public final static String ACTION_RESUME = "com.example.package.receiver.action_resume";
    public final static String ACTION_STOP = "com.example.package.receiver.action_stop";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent==null)
            return;

        final String action = intent.getAction(); 
        if(ACTION_PAUSE.equals(action)) {
            // handle pause action and refresh notification
        } else if(ACTION_RESUME.equals(action)) {
            // handle resume action and refresh notification
        } else if(ACTION_STOP.equals(action)) {
            // handle stop action and refresh notification
        }
    }
}
```

Last step is to declare your receiver in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.package.receiver.MediaPlayerActionsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.package.receiver.action_pause" />
        <action android:name="com.example.package.receiver.action_resume" />
        <action android:name="com.example.package.receiver.action_stop" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: So from where i need to update the notification,? I have an activity for pausePendingIntent, from pauseActivity, Can I Update?

Comment: Basically you can update notifications from anywhere (you only need a `context` for that). BTW. Why are you using Activities as your actions pendingIntents? You the device needs to display anything after clicking on that action? If not (if just resume/pause/stop the music) you should use `BroadcastReceiver` for that (instead of `Activity`). It will let you handle the action without showing any UI.

Comment: Ya, exactly.  I don't want to display anything after clicking on the actions, how can i implement the broadcast receiver for this purpose, If you don't mind can you help me with an example?

Comment: No problem. I've also added declarations of these actions names as final static String fields. This way you don't need to re-type them every time you use it. This will help you recude a chance of errors in later code changes:)